# Why is it that these JButtons aren't being created?

Tags: java, swing

I used Java graphics to create a 500 x 500 Checkers board within a JPanel, which was placed within a JFrame. To make the pieces, I wrote a series of for loops to create JButtons across the board. The following for loops correctly set up the pieces for one side of the board:

```
    for(int x = 355; x>=55;x-=100)
    {
     Piece p = new Piece();


     p.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


     p.setBounds(x,5,40,40);

     b.add(p);
    }

    for(int x = 5;x<=355; x+=100)
    {
        Piece p = new Piece();
        p.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        p.setBounds(x,55,40,40);
        b.add(p);

    }


     for(int x = 355; x>=55;x-=100)
    {
     Piece p = new Piece();
     p.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
     p.setBounds(x,105,40,40);
     b.add(p);
    }
```

However, I just started setting up the pieces for the other side of the board with this for loop, and none of the buttons are being displayed:

```
     for(int x = 5; x>=355;x+=100)
    {
     Piece p = new Piece();


     p.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


     p.setBounds(x,255,40,40);

     b.add(p);
    }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't know about others, but for me to figure out what was wrong, I'd need to see a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that would let me experience your problem for myself. I also have to look askance at your use of absolute positioning. If this were my program, my chess board would be a JPanel that held an 8 x 8 grid of colored JPanels, and I'd place my pieces in the center of the holding square (JPanel). Giving each square JPanel a GridBagLayout would allow it to hold the one piece in its center.

Comment: What is `b`?  Where is it defined?

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead [use layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop

```
for (int x = 5; x >= 355; x += 100) {
    ... 
}
```

won't ever be entered.

You are setting `x` to `5`. Then, you are checking if `x >= 355`, which **will be `false`** because `5` is not `>= 355`.